# Graphics problem after Ubuntu 12.04 installation

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, system-installation, graphics

What I got after ubuntu 12.04 installation:

[image: screenshot]

Any solution?

Comment: we are going to need hardware information to help you. What graphics card do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to [Nvidia Drivers Center](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) and download your driver.

**1. Remove any previous Nvidia driver**

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

**2. Black list the Nouveau driver**

Run these commands:

```
sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/disable-nouveau.conf
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/disable-nouveau.conf
```

Add the following two lines, save and close:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

**3. Logout your session**

Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and login with your username and password.

**4. Turn off Xorg and install Nvidia driver**

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo sh ./your-nvidia-driver-file.run
```